# limited size; add, remove and shuffle

Tags: c#, java, big-o, abstract-data-type

Adding to the queue would be O(1). So what would be the removing efficiency? I am slightly confused about this.  It makes sense for it to be O(1) because we are removing from the head but what if the queue reaches it's max limit of 5 therefore before inserting a new element, the queue would have to dequeue by 1 and move/shuffle the top 4 elements towards the front to insert the new element at the rear (5th position). Would it still be O(1)?  Or maybe O(n) because of shuffling method.

I don't need codes or in depth explanation, just a logical explanation would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the queue is implemented as a circular buffer, as, for example the .NET `Queue` class is, then that's still an O(1) operation, even if you're both adding one item to the end and removing one item from the head.  Being a circular buffer it won't need to move all of the items, it simply need to adjust two integer indexes representing where the start/end of the queue is within the buffer.

On top of that, if there's a capacity of 5 then you can say that even if you *did* need to move all of the items, you are never moving more than 5.  Everything is O(1) when n is small.  Big O is only relevant when 'n' can scale to large numbers.